# Laravel/Symfony: response download file not returning correct size

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I use Nginx + PHP-FPM and an Amazon Linux 2 server.

I've a file called myplugin.zip with size 34KB

```
[root@ip-172-33-4-164 laravel-app]# ls -la /tmp/R2birI4LuZ/myplugin.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx nginx 35889 May  6 16:21 /tmp/R2birI4LuZ/myplugin.zip
```

The file unzips perfectly using "unzip " on lunix.

However, when I try to send the file as a response using Symfony's Binary class:

```
$path = /tmp/R2birI4LuZ/myplugin.zip;

$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' =>  'Binary',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.basename($path),
    "Content-Length: ".filesize($path)
];

$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($path, 200 , $headers);
return $response;
```

I also tried

The file returned to my MacOS through Chrome has wrong size and is corrupt

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Dev-Mac  staff  59940 May  6 18:21 myplugin.zip
```

Note that I also tried the following Laravel download() and the same size is returned (59940 bytes): 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just leave the filesize out?
Just `return new BinaryFileResponse($path);`

Comment: also changed mime type to octet/stream or similar?

Comment: yup! it is driving me crazy.